# Background scrolling in opposite direction

Tags: javascript, css

I made a simple edit in this code that actually works in moving the background in the opposite direction of the scroll but is leaving a blank gap on the top (even if the background is set to repeat). 
Just took out the "-" minus sign to the -(scrolled*0.15)+'px').

```
function parallax(){
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.background').css('top',(scrolled*0.15)+'px');
}
```

As you can see, it works but the background leaves a big chunk of white on the top.
Am I missing something? Thanks a lot!

https://codepen.io/prandam/pen/LYpONZx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bodyHeight = parseInt($('body').height());
var bgTop = -1*bodyHeight;
$('.background').css({
  height: (bodyHeight*2)+'px',
  top: bgTop+'px'
});

$(window).scroll(function(e){
  parallax(); 
});

function parallax() {
  var newTop = bgTop + $(window).scrollTop()*0.15; 
  if (newTop === 0) return;
  $('.background').css('top', newTop+'px');
}
```

code is enough, self explaining

Answer (score 0):

All background repeat does is allow you to have a larger height.
The element with the background is still sitting at the top of the page.
Your initial top is 0px.
Which means as soon as you add anymore top you will get white space.

Set initial top to be -500px.
Change your scroll code to this:

```
  $('.background').css('top',(-500 + scrolled*0.15)+'px');
```